# Issue with looping over a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

So I have this code here, but when I get to the last for loop, it only spits back one word, instead of an amount of x's and *'s for the rest of the dictionary. Any help is appreciated

```
def main():
    print(parse_string("I had a good dog not a cat. A dog eats pizzas. A dog is happy. There is a happy dog there in the dog park."))
def parse_string(string):
    dicto = {}
    ast = ['*']
    x = ['X']
    boring = ['to', 'the', 'and', 'i', 'of', 'he', 'she',
            'a', "ill", "ive", 'but', 'by', 'we', 'whose'
            , 'how', 'go', 'such', 'this', 'me', 'can', "shes", "hes"
            , 'have', 'has', 'had', 'an', 'did', 'so', 'to', "well", 'on'
            , 'him', 'well', 'or', 'be', 'as', 'those', 'there', 'are', 'do'
            , 'too', 'if', 'it', 'at', 'what', 'you', 'will', 'in', 'with'
            , 'not', 'for', 'is', 'my', 'o', 'her', 'his', 'am']
    newstring = string.lower()
    newstring = newstring.replace('.', '')
    newstring = newstring.replace("'", '')
    finalstring = newstring.split()
    for word in finalstring:
        if word not in boring:
            if word not in dicto:
                dicto[word] = 1
            else:
                dicto[word] += 1
    for wrd in dicto:
        xmult = dicto[wrd] // 5
        astmult = dicto[wrd] % 5
        if xmult >= 1:
            return wrd + " " + xmult*x[0] + " " + astmult*ast[0]
        else:
            return wrd + " " + astmult*ast[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what this code _is_ doing and what it _should be_ doing? You are way more likely to get a reasonable answer if people do not have to study what you wrote in order to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

When you loop through your dictionary you are calling `return` inside of your loop. The instant one of those criteria are met, your function returns, not finishing the rest of the loop. I made some modifications to your last few lines:

```
return_string = ""
for wrd in dicto:
    xmult = dicto[wrd] // 5
    astmult = dicto[wrd] % 5
    if xmult >= 1:
        return_string += wrd + " " + xmult*x[0] + " " + astmult*ast[0] + '\n'
    else:
        return_string += wrd + " " + astmult*ast[0] + '\n'
return return_string
```